# How to have "Add to cart" button in cs-cart php controller

Tags: php, button, add-on, cs-cart

I am trying to make a "required" addon for cs-cart that gives a pop up showing the products that are also required for a selected product in the checkout summary page.

I have been able to make the pop up work using "checkout.post.php" in my add-on, and I create the popup using:

$msg = Registry::get('view')->fetch('addons/my_new_addon/custom_product_notification.tpl'); 
fn_set_notification('I', __('custom_product_notification_title'), $msg, 'P');

However, I have not yet been able to put "add to cart" button for the products I am going to suggest in this popup. Can someone point me the right direction?

Comment: can you please provide a much more deeper description about your modification?
And did you check this add-on? http://kb.cs-cart.com/requred-products

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response. I have seen that addon, but I do not want to force required products, just suggest them. Now I have made some modifications and added a controller that runs when "checkout summary" is requested. In that conrtoller I have the mentioned 2 liners. I am able to pass on the $product to custom_product_notification.tpl using registry::assign, but I can not make the "add to cart" button work on the tpl file.  I can pasted the whole code if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the **product_data.tpl** template called from your template? Try to add **show_add_to_cart=true** parameter when the template is included.

Comment: Well not particularly.. Thank you so much for your response though. I ended up making the add on with some workarounds.